# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'. cant understand this error

Tags: sql, group-by, average, having-clause

```
select SNo 
from Supplier  
Having AVG(Qty) IN (
    Select SNo, AVG(Qty)AS Average 
    from Supplier 
    Group By SNo 
)
where (Qty) >50 AND (Qty) <100;
```

Comment: I can't imagine what you are trying to do.  They query has numerous errors.  I would suggest that you delete this question and ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: I Need to Select SNo  from tables with average Qty and more than 50 and less than 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:

> I Need to Select SNo from tables with average Qty and more than 50 and less than 100

For this, you can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select sno, avg(qty) avg_qty
from supplier
group by sno
having avg(qty) > 50 and avg(qty) < 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply do aggregation without subquery :

```
select sno, avg(Qty) AS Average 
from supplier s
where qty > 50 and qty < 100
group by sno;
```

If you want filter with aggregated values then you can do :

```
select sno, avg(Qty) AS Average 
from supplier s
group by sno
having avg(qty) > 50 and avg(qty) < 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, but I believe that's this:

```
select tbaux.SNo from
(Select SNo, AVG(Qty) AS Average from Supplier Group By SNo ) as tbaux
where (tbaux.Qty) >50 AND (tbaux.Qty) <100;
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. for your reply